# How to resolve this error in in-app billing?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
    at com.android.vending.billing.IMarketBillingService$Stub$Proxy.sendBillingRequest(IMarketBillingService.java:100)
    at kr.my.dungeons.BillingService$CheckBillingSupported.run(BillingService.java:209)
    at kr.my.dungeons.BillingService$BillingRequest.runIfConnected(BillingService.java:127)
    at kr.my.dungeons.BillingService.runPendingRequests(BillingService.java:609)
    at kr.my.dungeons.BillingService.onServiceConnected(BillingService.java:654)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1049)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1066)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4002)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

That is error syntax.

1. Get sample source from SDK.
2. Put 'public key' in Security.java from google market.
3. My source path is 'src/kr/my/' and aidl file path is 'src/com/android/vending/billing/'.
4. Checked AndroidManifest.xml.
5. Upload apk to google market. (not published)
6. add 'sword_001', 'potion_001' in google market.(published)
7. Installed same apk on device.

(same error in sample source from https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary)

What Did I mistake?

Comment: I was fixed to reset my device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when the user has not accepted the Market EULA

So launch the EULA

```
 try {
    CALL BILLING CODE HERE .....
  } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    initialiseMarket();
  }

private void initialiseMarket() {
  new AlertDialog.Builder(this).
    setTitle("Android Market").
    setNeutralButton("CLOSE"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search"));
        startActivity(intent);
      }
    }).
    setMessage("Android Market not initialised. Please accept EULA and restart.").
    show();
}
```

<sub>[Taken from here](http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=25)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on fixing this here https://github.com/drewjw81/AndroidBillingLibrary

This version should display an alert when it can't bind to Play correctly.

If you use it, remember it still needs some work so please test, also please file a bug report on my page if the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known In-App Billing bug reported [here](http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=25).

I've added a `catch` to the [AndroidBillingLibrary](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary) when this occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Read my answer here:

[android in-app billing - restoreTransactionInformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763761/android-in-app-billing-restoretransactioninformation/10179769#10179769)

I'm assuming you tried to restore transactions because a bunch of users (including me) were seeing this stack trace while doing so.

The error occurs because of a null field (the 'notification_id' field) added to the CONFIRM_TRANSACTIONS request sent back when you call a restoreTransactions.