# android: in app billing RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I got this kind of error from last night..i dont't know what's going on.Is there any problem from my side?. I didn't change my code but when i clear data or i restall the application it shows me like....!!!!!! frustrating........

```
05-05 04:18:16.000: E/Finsky(17538): [1] NotifyingErrorListener.onErrorResponse: Server error on InAppPurchaseInformationRequest: com.android.volley.ServerError

05-05 04:18:16.010: D/Finsky(17538): [1] MarketBillingService.sendResponseCode: Sending response RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE for request 227869xxxxxxx6110 to com.mypackage.
MarketBillingService.sendResponseCode: Sending response RESULT_ERROR for request 227869xxxxxxx6110 to com.mypackage.
```

someone says reinstall the app from market..ya its one solution but is there any other way?????

I just want to know is there any problem from my side...??

[android in-app billing - restoreTransactionInformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763761/android-in-app-billing-restoretransactioninformation) says "although you do not need to respond to this intent with a CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS message".If i implement this but is any one is having experience of this, would be great.

Help me

Thanks in advance...

Comment: i uninstalled the app and reinstalled from market then its working but can i have othe solution?????????

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you find this message in the log:

05-30 09:28:23.760: E/Volley(4636): [13] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 429 for https://android.clients.google.com/vending/api/ApiRequest

it means that you've send too much RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS request in given amount of time. Google has clearly some throttling on request. It happened to me during testing in-app billing, approx. 20-30 restore transcations request went ok, and then - service unavailable response.

Comment: Thank you for answer.. actually  I knew it, it was happening because i have tested my application so many time that's why i was getting this kind of error.

Comment: but this problem is permanent? Because after several hours i still receive the same error code.

Comment: Any indication how long it took for this error to subside? or what steps you took to resolve it?

Comment: I was experiencing this error for longer than two days, than, after three weeks I returned to that app and it worked again... so the lockout time is somewhere between. Not very cool from google.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you get this message because Google Play application was not running at the moment, and after you reinstalled the app, Google Play was up and running again.

When you encounter the same problem again, try to start Google Play application and then get back to your app and try to access billing once more.

Comment: It's not like that because i am having 7 in app product and i'm getting this message in only 2 in app product which i have already purchased from market.Other in app products are not having this kind of message.

Comment: I got to know that is so many testing in very short time from one email id results this kind of message.